# xcode KML Viewer display only around 5miles on map

Tags: ios, maps

I have a KML file with over 2000 Places but when i use that is taking more than  5 minutes for loading all places.  now my question is whether it is possible to load the map with only places around 5 miles from local place and add a button for user so that when they need click it to use all places.

Please help me i am hobby programmer and dont find a solution thank you for advance

Answer (score 1):

You should create [`CLLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) objects for your `currentLocation` and the `placemarkLocation` of the particular KML placemark, and then you can use [`distanceFromLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW18) to see how far they are (in meters). And given that there are 1,609.34 meters per mile, five miles is therefore 8,046.72 meters:

```
CLLocation *placemarkLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude
                                                           longitude:longitude];

if ([placemarkLocation distanceFromLocation:currentLocation] < 8046.72)
{
    // add placemark to map
}
else
{
    // don't
}
```

---

I have two follow-up observations:

1. You said that the loading process is taking 5 minutes. I find that very suspicious and wonder if you have something else going on. I just, for giggles and grins, added 2000 annotations to a map, and it took a few seconds, not a few minutes. I'd suggest you do some diagnosis to identify the source of your delay, because there's no point in optimizing the map generation if the problem is the XML parsing or something else. Do some diagnostic work to identify what's actually the source of your delay.

   If for example, the problem is that you are downloading over the Internet a huge KML file, which is measured in tens or hundreds of megabytes, any optimization of the `MKMapView` will have negligible impact on the overall performance. This is just a random example, but make sure you really understand the source of the problem.
2. While adding 2000 annotations to my `MKMapView` on an iPhone 5 took a few seconds, it's obviously not a great UX (both in terms of the few second delay, but also the idea of having two thousand annotations which you obviously cannot visually differentiate on an iPhone screen). You suggested grabbing the placemarks that are within 5 miles and that you give the user the option to alternative choose them all. I might, I'd suggest a different approach:

   Rather than coding this "five miles or all" logic, I'd suggest that you look at the `region` or `visibleMapRect` for the `MKMapView`, and show the annotations that fall within that region or `MKMapRect`. Or, even better, just show 100 of the annotations that fall within the region. And if you hooked this into [`regionDidChangeAnimated`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-SW4) routine, it would get new annotations as they were needed.